# 404 a directory in nginx server block

Tags: nginx

In my /conf.d/ folder I have a .conf file as follows:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

You can see that it redirect any http traffic to https, that is fine.

However, there are certain http URLs, like http://www.example.com/profile/(.*) that I want to 404 immediately, without the redirect to the https version first.

I have tried variants of the following code with no success, the URL, eg http://www.example.com/profile/abc123, is always redirected to the https version.

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    location ~* ^/profile/ {
    return 404;
    }
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
```

Note that I want to capture example.com/profile/ and any pages that match that, eg example.com/profile/abc123 etc

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

    location ~ ^/profile/ {
    return 404;
    }

server_name example.com *.example.com;

    location ~ ^/ {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why not to use prefix locations (`location / { ... }`, `location /profile/ { ... }`) for that kind of configuration? Regex matching locations is just an extra overhead.

Comment: I posted that answer and also asked the question. To answer your question, I don't know what prefix locations are. Would you mind putting that into an answer I can use? Thanks